# How to automatically convert all Enumerable to List when using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have this POST endpoint in my ASP.NET Core Web API (with Entity Framework):

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Game>> PostGame(Game game) {

  ...

  game.State = new GameState();
  game.State.Map.Rows = game.State.Map.Rows.ToList();

  ...
}
```

Then I have these two classes:

```
public class MapRow {

  public int Id { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<MapColumn> Columns { get; set; }

  public MapRow() { }

  public MapRow(IEnumerable<MapColumn> columns) {
    Columns = columns;
  }
}

public class Map {

  public long Id { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<MapRow> Rows { get; set; }

  public Map() { }

  public Map(IEnumerable<MapRow> rows) {
    Rows = rows;
  }
}
```

Which has two `Enumerable`s that need to be converted to a `List` or Entity Framework will throw  an error similar to this:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The type of navigation property 'Columns' on the entity type 'MapRow' is 'SelectRangeIterator' which does not implement ICollection. Collection navigation properties must implement ICollection<> of the target type.

I solved this error for my `Rows` by calling `.ToList()` in the endpoint itself. However since there are multiple endpoints and you can have `Enumerable`s that are quite nested it's quickly becoming unmaintainable having to convert every `Enumerable` to a `List` manually.

Is there an easier way that would allow me to automate this?

Comment: You should use ICollection at least for navigation properties.

Comment: Dont use your entity types in your public api. Map to and from them. It would solve this issue as well as some others (ie over posting)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Would you mind expanding your comment as an answer? I literally started with C# yesterday and have no clue what you mean :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For EF entities, navigation properties for collections should be declared as `ICollection<T>` rather than `IEnumerable<T>`. So for instance:

```
public class MapRow {

  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<MapColumn> Columns { get; set; } = new List<MapColumn>();

  public MapRow() { }

  public MapRow(IEnumerable<MapColumn> columns) {
    Columns = columns;
  }
}

public class Map {

  public long Id { get; set; }
  public virtual IColleciton<MapRow> Rows { get; set; } = new List<MapRow>();

  public Map() { }

  public Map(IEnumerable<MapRow> rows) {
    Rows = rows;
  }
}
```

`ICollection<T>` extends `IEnumerable<T>` so any method expecting IEnumerable will be perfectly content with ICollection. It's a different story when you try passing an IEnumerable to something expecting IList or ICollection.

Declaring them as `virtual` also allows for EF to assign proxies to these properties to assist with lazy loading if they are needed and the DbContext is still available. It also helps to auto-initialize the properties to a new collection so that when new-ing up a Map, you can immediately start adding Rows and Columns without risking `NullReferenceException`s.

Comment: Interesting. Does it matter if I have `= new List<MapRow>();`since I pass in a list with the constructor?

Comment: No, that constructor would overwrite the reference, though you still have a default constructor that is available that does not, so it just serves as a catch-all to ensure any new entity is ready to go for accepting items in its collections.

Comment: Mmh alright. Only reason for the empty constructors is that EF threw errors telling me I needed them, for whatever reason unknown to me. I'll test this when I can and accept answer if it works as expected :)

Comment: Yes, EF needs to be able to construct the entities, so it won't necessarily know all required children state or potential arbitrary default values to pass to a constructor. Default initializers help keep new objects in a usable state.